# trigger Java EE batch from cron

Tags: java, cron, batch-processing, java-ee-7

JavaEE 7 appservers support batch operations implementing JSR 352 (Glassfish and Wildfly do).

What is a good way to start batch operations from Unix cron?

- exec wget/curl a rest servlet that starts the batch
- exec java that calls via JMX the appserver (slow java start, is there a JMX for C?)
- ??

Comment: The question is about triggering the batch job from outside the application server, not about JEE scheduling services.
Many IT operations want to start batch jobs by enterprise scheduling systems like cron or uc4.
One might even try to trigger from Jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

Scheduling a Java EE 7 Batch job can be done in couple of ways:

- Using @Schedule annotation which supports cron-like syntax
- Using ManagedScheduledExecutorService

More details at:

http://blog.arungupta.me/2014/07/schedule-javaee7-batch-jobs-techtip36/

If you want to invoke using curl, then you can put the code in a REST endpoint using @GET annotation. Add a command to invoke this endpoint in crontab.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to start a Jboss EAP 7 batch job (Java EE 7 JSR 352 compliant) by the jboss-cli.sh (starts asynchronously).

source: Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 7.0 Configuration Guide.

Wildfly should be similar.

Below is an example of a bash script for starting a JBOSS EAP7 batch job:

```
#!/bin/bash
JBOSS_HOME=/path_to_jboss_eap7_directory
DEPLOY=my_deploy_name.war
JOB_NAME=my_batch_name.xml

$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh \
        --connect \
        --command="/deployment=$DEPLOY/\
        subsystem=batch-jberet:\
        start-job(job-xml-name=$JOB_NAME)"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Java EE 7 supports cron jobs through the [`@Schedule`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html) annotation. You can use a method to fire your batch work. Here's a basic example:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class CronJobs {
    @Resource
    TimerService timerService;

    public void setTimer(long intervalDuration) {
        Timer timer = timerService.createTimer(intervalDuration, 
            "Created new programmatic timer");
    }

    @Schedule(second = "0", minute = "0", hour = "*/1")
    public void fireFooBatch() {
        JobOperator jobOperator = BatchRuntime.getJobOperator();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("someProperty", "someValue");
        long execID = jobOperator.start("yourJob", props);
    }
}
```

More info:

- [Java EE 7 Tutorial. 34.4 Using the Timer Service.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/ejb-basicexamples004.htm)
- [Java EE 7 Tutorial. 55 Batch Processing.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/batch-processing.htm#GKJIQ6)

Comment: Thanks, but this is a start from within the appserver. I'am looking for the best way to trigger a batch start from outside the appserver, from a shell script triggered in cron.

Comment: If you're not content to start from within the app server, you probably are outside the scope of the specification and into implementation-specific solutions.  Which app server and/or batch implementation are you using?   (I know this is a very late reply but maybe still of some value).